# Common methods for loading ribbon, combobox and dropdownbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ribbon-based UI which has one combobox and one dropdown box. I have created the following methods to load these controls with content:

For the Combobox:

```
        internal void LoadComboBox(RibbonComboBox YourCbx, List<string> YourList)
        {
            if (YourCbx.Items.Count > 0)
                YourCbx.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var curEntry in YourList.ToArray())
            {
                RibbonDropDownItem newItem = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                newItem.Label = curEntry ;
                YourCbx.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

For the Dropdown Box:

```
        internal void LoadDDBox(RibbonDropDown YourDD, List<string> YourList)
        {
            if (YourDD.Items.Count > 0)
                YourDD.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var curEntry in YourList.ToArray())
            {
                RibbonDropDownItem newItem = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                newItem.Label = curEntry ;
                YourDD.Items.Add(newItem);
            }

        }
```

As you can see, both methods are pretty much identical, with the exception that a different windows control object needs to be passed to the method. So I thought of creating one single method for both controls, and came as far as this:

```
        internal void LoadDropDown<T>(IList<T> YourDD, List<string> YourList, Action<RibbonDropDownItem> addMeth)
        {
            if (YourDD.Count > 0)
                YourDD.Clear();
            foreach (var curCS in YourList.ToArray())
            {
                RibbonDropDownItem newItem = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                newItem.Label = curCS;
                addMeth(newItem);
            }

        }
```

A call to this method could then look like this:

```
LoadDropDown<RibbonDropDown>((IList<RibbonDropDown>)MyDropDownControl, MyList,
                             (x) => { MyDropDownControl.Items.Add(x); });
```

Unfortunately, I get a runtime exception stating that RibbonDropDown can't be converted into IList. I am now stuck here. Does anyone have a suggestion how to make one method both above?

Comment: In the usage, you are trying to cast `MyDropDownControl` to an `IList<RibbonDropDown>`... Consider re-evaluating that, I don't think `MyDropDownControl` is a `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the idea to refer to a common base class was not fruitful, because both RibbonDropDown and RibbonComboxBox are interfaces in the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon namespace, and not classes.

But I have now found at last the correct solution. When looking at the Items member of both interfaces in VS, one sees that both implement `IList<RibbonDropDownItem>`. So the correct method is now the following:

```cs
internal void LoadDropDown(IList<RibbonDropDownItem> YourDD, List<string> YourList)
{
    if (YourDD.Count > 0)
        YourDD.Clear();
    foreach (var curCS in YourList.ToArray())
    {
        RibbonDropDownItem newItem = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
        newItem.Label = curCS;
        YourDD.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

and calling this method now looks like this (and works!):

```cs
LoadDropDown((IList<RibbonDropDownItem>)MyDropDownControl.Items, MyList);
```

Thanks anyhow for the inspiration to find the right solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your method like this:

```
      internal void LoadDropDown<T>(T YourDD, List<string> YourList, Action<RibbonDropDownItem> addMeth) where T : (AnyBaseTypeForRibbonItems)
        {
            if (YourDD.Items.Count > 0)
               YourDD.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var curCS in YourList.ToArray())
            {
                RibbonDropDownItem newItem = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                newItem.Label = curCS;
                addMeth(newItem);
            }

        }
```

And use it like this:

```
LoadDropDown<RibbonDropDown>(MyDropDownControl, MyList,
                             (x) => { MyDropDownControl.Items.Add(x); });
```